# Use default typewriter font only for a part of the document

Tags: fonts, typewriter

I'm using the `Inconsolata` font provided by the `zi4` package. But for a single macro, I want to use the default typewriter font (so not `Inconsolata`). Every other occurrence of `\texttt` in the document should use `Inconsolata`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[varqu]{zi4}

\newcommand{\csharp}{C\texttt{\#}} % How can I use the default typewriter font here?    

\begin{document}
  This should be \texttt{Inconsolata}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `\fontfamily` command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[varqu]{zi4}

\newcommand{\csharp}{C{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\#}}

\begin{document}
    \csharp\par
  This should be \texttt{Inconsolata}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfect for me :)